# Angular Hybrid: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ng-upgrade

I have an NgUpgrade app where I'm migrating from Angular.js's UI-Router to Angular's Router and everything was going well until I introduced a lazy-loaded module. Then, in one of the components from the lazy-loaded module I got this:

```
Found an error while navigating to /my-lazy-feature error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at new MyComponent (my.component.ts:86)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.MyComponent_Factory [as factory] (my.component.ts:147)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3503)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:9988)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:9337)
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14559)
    at MyOtherComponent_Template (my-other.component.ts:21)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9310)
    at renderView (core.js:9117)
    at renderComponent (core.js:10392)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:8982)
    at renderView (core.js:9142)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:24837)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.js:22876)
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:5182)
```

This error is generated in the expression `upgrade.$injector.get`, in which I try to get a reference to one of the Angular.js services:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
        this.state = upgrade.$injector.get("$state");
        this.stateParams = upgrade.$injector.get("$stateParams");
    }
```

From inside `MyComponent` I do `console.log(upgrade)` and I see there is no `upgrade.$injector`, but if I do the same from a non-lazy-loaded module, I see `$injector` is defined ok.

So there seem to be 2 instances of `UpgradeModule`. What can be the reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being, the lazy-loaded module was importing a module that was importing `UpgradeModule`, thus creating a second instance.

To fix it, ensure you only import `UpgradeModule` in the main module of your application. Even if your other modules need to access `UpgradeModule`, there is only need to import it once.